# Watching [absolute-path] and all sub-directories not excluded by your .gitignore. Will not monitor dotfiles

Tags: tailwind-css

While I was trying to start the Tailwind CLI build process, I got the following error using this command:

```
npx run build
```

> Watching C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\xxxxx\portifolio and all
> sub-directories not excluded by your .gitignore. Will not monitor
> dotfiles. Found & ignored ./node_modules ; is listed in .gitignore
> Found & ignored ./public\style.css ; has ignored extension Found &
> ignored ./src\style.css ; has ignored extension
>
> Starting: build node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\xxxxx\portifolio\build'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

in package.json I have the following code

```
{
  "name": "portifolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tailwindcss -i src/style.css -o public/style.css"
    },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6"
  }
}
```